# Can I add my Maps application to "Android Auto" just like how Waze and Google Map does?

Tags: android, android-auto, waze

I am trying to build apps for android Auto. I can use MediaSession API to register music apps to show in Android Auto. Similarly Can I register my maps application to show in Android Auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot integrate a turn by turn navigation app (maps) using the Public SDK. Currently, [Android Auto public templates](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/) that are available for developers to build off of, support either media or messaging only.

Comment: How is Waze able todo this?

Comment: They're partnered with, and I believe owned by Google. As far as I can tell they are the only ones currently allowed to do so.